# Angular drag and drop with nested not working as intended

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-dragdrop

I'm having an issue that CDK Drag and Drop is not working as how I want it to be.
There is one scenario that I can't get it working and that is moving and IT (green object) inside a different (green object) as you can see in my example below the my Sub cdkDropList is never recognized as a dropArea.

I have tried changing my cdkDropListConnectedTo multiple times but I never get it to work.

I already googled online for multiple solutions and I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Here below you can see my example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-nested-drag-drop-tree-structure-gkt1kk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

This is how the example starts a

[image: t1]

and this is what I want to happen if I were to drag the IT1 into the sub of IT3

[image]

Comment: Please add more detail of what you mean by _"how I want it to be"_, some tips: try comparing "current behavior" vs "expected behaviour", and... since your requirement seems to be a visual one, maybe a little prototype/image showing what is wrong with your current approach _(in my case, I don't understand at all what you need)_

Comment: @luiscla27 I added an image specifying what I mean. I hope it is clear now

Comment: Try this on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-nested-drag-drop-demo

Comment: if i remember my attepmts at this correctly the problem is that the first droplist moves away so youre not actually entering the inner one lemme check my old project one moment
i think the main point was the cdkDropListEnterPredicate but its been a while and the code i wrote back then sucks 

also try cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true" (i found that on a bunch of them)

Comment: i think you just forgot the 

        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="getConnectedListForItemsAndCategories()"
on the innermost level 
https://angular-cdk-nested-drag-drop-tree-structure-2gztlp.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you just forgot the

```
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="getConnectedListForItemsAndCategories()"
```

on the innermost of the 3 levels to allow moving them in

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-nested-drag-drop-tree-structure-zvsafw
but you also need to add the drop function to "persist" the changes afterwards.
for that cdk provides 2 functions but you need the containers to reference the arrays (which can be added with )

> [cdkDropListData]=""

Comment: For some reason the stackblitz link doesn't seem to be working on my end. I get a white screen that keeps loading indefinitely. I tried adding the     [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="getConnectedListForItemsAndCategories()"
like you said but I still keep getting exact the same behaviour https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-nested-drag-drop-tree-structure-rwft29?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Ah shoot I think I failed to save it or something :/ gonna take another look tomorrow

Comment: ok new link (it wasnt just using the getConnectedListForItemsAndCategories for the last one , but i also seem to have used it for all the others ) probably easier to finetune it afterwards once the drag works , then u can still remove those that arent wanted ^^

Comment: i think you'll have a better time if you do a conceptual differentiation between dropLists (i.e. html elements that contain dragndroppable items and cdkDrag elements that are those that can be drag n dropped) basically every binding with "list" in it should be on the parent container

Comment: Thank you for the help. It does indeed look to be working as intended! I will implement it on my production code and play around with it.